# Angular 1.3 : TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null error on ng-submit

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a simple form that I am trying to submit but it is giving me error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null.

I removed almost everything but it is still giving me error. I don't know why.

Here is the code.

```
<body id="home" ng-app="formApp">
    <div ng-controller="formRegister">
<form name="formprofile3" method="post" id="formprofile3" role="form" ng-submit="formprofile3()">
<!--<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Your Name" ng-model="formData.fname" title="Please Enter Your First Name" class="form-control input-sm" required="required">
</div>
 
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" ng-model="formData.email" class="form-control input-sm" title="Please Enter Your Valid Email" required="required">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" ng-model="formData.subject" title="Please enter Subject" class="form-control input-sm" required="required">
</div>
 
<div class="form-group">
<textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" title="Please enter your message/concern/query" ng-model="formData.msg" class="form-control input-sm" required="required"></textarea>
 
</div>  -->  

<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name="btn-register" id="btn-register" required="required">Submit</button>
 
</div>
</form>
```

**Angular Code.**

```
    var formApp = angular.module('formApp', []);

formApp.controller('formRegister', function($scope,$http){
      
            $scope.formData = {};
    
    $scope.formprofile3 = function() {
                       alert('hi');
      /*       var allData={'formData': $scope.formData}
        $http({
              method  : 'POST',
              url     : 'http://xyzcom/contact.php',
              data : allData,
              headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  
          })
              .success(function(data) {
                   if (!data.success) {
 
                      $scope.message = data.errors.message;
                   
                  }else{
                   $scope.message = '';
                      alert('Your message has been sent.');
                      location.href = './profile.html';
                  }

              });*/
                   };
```

As you can see most of them are comment out but still I am getting error.

Comment: Try changing your form name to something different other than ng-submits value

Answer (score 0):

Here, [form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) is considered as angular directive which instantiate [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController). If the `name` attribute of `form` directive is specified, the form controller is published onto the current scope under this name.  So when you're writing ng-submit function name same as form name attribute it try to (search and) execute in that newly created scope. Name that function other than form name & issue will be solved.

Example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BfVbvoblT6Tbz5oEO5o0?p=preview) (Change form name to same as ng-submit function to reproduce the issue).